# Why did John Scott attempt to kill Olivia in Fringe?

Tags: tv, fringe

Since John Scott is later revealed to not be the traitor that we had thought that he was, why, near the end of the pilot episode, did he try to kill Olivia?
I have seen all the episodes of the tv show but this (alongside other questions later to come) remains unanswered. Or should I say forgotten as a plotline?
But still this bugs me. Why did he try to kill Olivia?

Comment: Fringe, to me, had more plot holes and flaws than any other tv show I can remember (still enjoyed it esp. John Noble though). I employed the 'accept it and don't question' approach to what I felt like they made up as they went along.

Comment: So you're saying you've forgotten Lost already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Fringe* had its overall plot elements pre-planned but was making up much of it as it went along, so they would later have to try (or not try) to explain things that didn't make obvious sense. Scott's later being cleared as a traitor makes his actions in the pilot episode harder to figure out. Well - he was cleared *as a traitor*, and his love for Olivia was proven to be legit, but this doesn't make him a good guy.

He apparently knew about the plane guy but let him kill everyone on the plane - or at the very least, failed to deal with it in time to prevent it. He then *murdered* the plane guy, presumably for trying to kill him and putting him through that whole ordeal. This is a rogue agent at this point, a murderer. A known murderer.

Olivia is chasing him and is about to arrest him. He's freaking out, being pursued, so he tries to run her off the road and stop her pursuit. Instinctive self-preservation behavior from a guy who has just been through a horrible traumatic ordeal, and who has just destroyed his life with his actions.